# Calling a class without using Classname X = new Classname();

Tags: java, function

I have a class with set and get, and In another class.
However, if I use `Classname X = new Classname();` I'll not be able to use previous information set before.

Here's part of the code:

```
public void BuscarID () throws Exception {
    //THIS VOID IS FOR SEARCH
    ConsumirWS2 http = new ConsumirWS2();
    Gson g = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").create();
    Cliente2 u = new Cliente2();
    Type ClienteType = new TypeToken<Cliente2>() {
    }.getType();

    int i = Integer.parseInt(InterfaceConsu2.jTextFieldID.getText());
    u.setCad_pes_id(i);
    String s = Integer.toString(u.getcad_pes_id());

    String url = "http://localhost:8080/clienteWebService/webresources/CadastroCliente/Clienteid/get/"+s;
    
    String json = http.sendGet(url, "GET");
    u = g.fromJson(json, ClienteType);
    System.out.println(json + ("\n"));
    System.out.println(u.getcad_pes_nome() +("\n") + u.getCad_pes_apelido() +("\n") + u.getCad_pes_cpf() +("\n") + u.getCad_pes_data()+("\n"));
    String Date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(u.getCad_pes_data());
    System.out.println(Date1);
    
    InterfaceConsu2.jTextFieldNOME.setText(u.getcad_pes_nome());
    InterfaceConsu2.jTextFieldAPELIDO.setText(u.getCad_pes_apelido());
    InterfaceConsu2.jFormattedTextFieldCPF.setText(u.getCad_pes_cpf());
    InterfaceConsu2.jFormattedTextFieldDATA.setText(Date1);
    InterfaceConsu2.jTextFieldID.setText(s);
}

    public void alterar () throws Exception {
    //THIS VOID IS FOR EDITING THE INFORMATION GET BEFORE
    ConsumirWS2 http = new ConsumirWS2();
    Gson g = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").create();
    Cliente2 u = new Cliente2();
    Type ClienteType = new TypeToken<Cliente2>() {
    }.getType();
    
    u.setCad_pes_nome(InterfaceConsu2.jTextFieldNOME.getText());
    u.setCad_pes_cpf(InterfaceConsu2.jFormattedTextFieldCPF.getText());
    u.setCad_pes_apelido(InterfaceConsu2.jTextFieldAPELIDO.getText());
    int i = Integer.parseInt(InterfaceConsu2.jTextFieldID.getText());
    u.setCad_pes_id(i);
    //u.setCad_pes_id(InterfaceConsu2.jTextFieldID.getText());
    SimpleDateFormat formatter  = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    java.util.Date utilDate = null;
                    try {
                        utilDate = formatter.parse(InterfaceConsu2.jFormattedTextFieldDATA.getText());
                    } catch (ParseException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(InterfaceConsu2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
    u.setCad_pes_data(sqlDate);
    
    String json = g.toJson(u, ClienteType);
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/clienteWebService/webresources/CadastroCliente/Cliente/alterar";
    
    http.sendPost(url, json, "PUT");
}
```

and then I have the set and get class:

```
public class Cliente2 {

public String cad_pes_nome;
public String cad_pes_apelido;
private String cad_pes_cpf;
public int cad_pes_id;
public Date cad_pes_data;

public String getcad_pes_nome() {
    return cad_pes_nome;
}

public void setCad_pes_nome(String cad_pes_nome) {
    this.cad_pes_nome = cad_pes_nome;
}

public String getCad_pes_apelido() {
    return cad_pes_apelido;
}

public void setCad_pes_apelido(String cad_pes_apelido) {
    this.cad_pes_apelido = cad_pes_apelido;
}

public String getCad_pes_cpf() {
    return cad_pes_cpf;
}

public void setCad_pes_cpf(String cad_pes_cpf) {
    this.cad_pes_cpf = cad_pes_cpf;
}
 public int getcad_pes_id() {
    return cad_pes_id;
}

public void setCad_pes_id(int cad_pes_id) {
    this.cad_pes_id = cad_pes_id;
}
public Date getCad_pes_data() {
    return cad_pes_data;
}

public void setCad_pes_data(Date cad_pes_data) {
    this.cad_pes_data = cad_pes_data;
}
```

}

Because I'm using `Classname X = new Classname();`, when I try to print my `u.getcad_pes_nome` or any other get, It's empty, There's a way to call `Cliente2` without using `Cliente2 u = new Cliente2();` or what I have to change in my classes?

Comment: You have to redesign your classes.  Creating a new variable isn't your problem.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, redesign how?

Comment: Your code makes it really unclear, but in general, you should stop editing the existing values and make new, separate values.